# Cannot connect to valid github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubymine

I have read/write access to a private repository owned by someone else but RubyMine cannot connect to the Git URL. Workflow:

```
Open RubyMine
Click on "Check out from source control"
Select Git
Enter URL, click "Test", and Test fails
```

I'm using OSX Lion and my Github credentials have already been saved. I've tried connecting to a few other github URLs on the "Explore" tab at github.com and I haven't had any trouble. Suggestions?

Comment: Copy the git clone URL from github and try it in the terminal, what does that say? `git clone https://github.com/yourname/repo.git`

Comment: It asks for my username, password, and then clones the repo successfully

Comment: In that case, double check your credentials stored RubyMine.

Comment: I tried that just now, it says "Connection Successful". I tried adding an extra character to my username, just to see what happens, and it throws an error message as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by following the tutorial on GitHub, Generating SSH Keys, exactly. I also deleted any existing keys in my account before adding a new one. In the RubyMine dialog, I pasted the ssh link to my repository instead of the HTTP one. Hope this helps someone else.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create an issue in [the RubyMine bugtracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com) and attach the log file there (Help -> Reveal Log in Finder). Maybe it is a bug in RubyMine support of Git over HTTP.

Meanwhile as a workaround you may use SSH, as [adviced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870022/72788) by user1836351.

Another workaround is specifying your credentials in the `~/.netrc` file.
Example of the file content:

```
machine github.com
login yourname
password yourpassword
```